# Image Source property, binding to image in Resources.resx file in XAML, how to?

Tags: xaml, resx, imagesource

I have a Resources.resx file, which contains localized strings and also localized images.  How do I bind an image to a property in XAML similar to the way a localized string is done (i.e., Text="{Binding Path=Resources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}")?

Is it possible to use this same method for Image source?